# Does it matter what edit review reject reason I pick?

Tags: support, review, edits, rejection-reasons

I saw a post that was borderline-vandalism.  It was an attempt at grammar/spelling improvement and left the post in about the same state.  In particular an "I" was changed to an "i."  I often write custom edits and did for this one, explaining...  not to do that.  From a review improvement standpoint custom edits are almost always preferable, since more explanatory.  However, I'm wondering if there is additional business logic tied to other reasons, e.g. since vandalism is so harsh, perhaps it would revoke the OP's edit privileges sooner, etc.

Comment: Not an answer, but during peak times, I try to avoid leaving custom reject messages because it is possible that someone will swoop in and approve the edit before I finish typing (has happened before)

Comment: @psubsee2003 You mean, all the time. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen not all the time.  I recall it not happening once maybe about a year ago :-)

Comment: You guys must type more slowly.

Comment: With more detail.

Comment: @djechlin: Don't forget not everyone is a native English speaker. I for one type about half-speed in English, compared to my native language, even though I'm (reasonably) fluent. ;-)

Comment: I (mistakenly) chose "spam/vandalism" instead of "too minor" once, and the editor said he'd quit the site because he was now "branded as a spammer". <sigh>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, I'm wondering if there is additional business logic tied to other reasons, e.g. since vandalism is so harsh, perhaps it would revoke the OP's edit privileges sooner, etc.

If three users select *vandalism* as rejection reason, the privilege of suggesting edits is not revoked earlier. Whatever reason you choose, users will not be able to suggest further edits for the next 7 days, after X suggestions of theirs are rejected.

The reason for rejecting the suggested edit is only important for the user who suggested it. Moderators generally don't suspend a user for suggesting bad edits. That could eventually happen for a user vandalizing posts written by others; even in that case, moderators don't normally check the number of suggested edits rejected as vandalism, except in the case a post in this very site or a flag points out the behavior of a user who, for example, keeps suggesting edits that change posts in non sense. In that case, marking a suggested edit as vandalism when it is effectively vandalism helps the moderators.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it matter what edit review reject reason I pick?

Mainly if the user who performed the edit is aware, and was genuinely trying to help. I'd like to think that's usually the case.

When I was a low reputation user in SO not too long ago, I used to check how my edits went (much like I do now with flags being a new 10K user, still learning!). Getting feedback, especially hand tailored feedback was really useful.

One feature request that (I think was already made) is to notify users when an edit they made was reject, leading to the edit screen when they can read why it was rejected.

If I feel that the user was just editing to rep, and no genuine attempt was made, or that one of the fixed reasons fits why I reject the edit perfectly, I don't bother writing a custom message.